# How to handle duplication of events caused by Storm's replay in case of fail() from one of the bolts

Tags: apache-storm

I have a Topology with Spout S, and 3 bolts - A, B, C.

Bolt A reads from Spout S. Bolt A then splits the data into Bolts B and C (based on some filter). Bolts B and C have their respective data sinks.

If I use Storm's anchoring and anchor the tuple at Bolt A, and then later on Bolt B ack's successfully, but Bolt C does a fail(). Will replaying by Storm at Spout S cause duplication of events at Bolt B and so into the data sink at B?

If so, what is the way to avoid that while still using storm's reliability feature of anchoring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storm's anchoring feature only support at-least-once processing and there is no support to handle duplicates in case of failure. Depending on you application semantics, this might be an issues or not.

For example if you do idempotent operation later on, duplicate are not issues (an example of an idempotent operation is updating a key-value store -- if you to two `put` operation because of a duplicate, the state of the key-value store still be the same).

If you have non idempotent operations and duplicates are an issue, you could try to take care if this by you own -- but this is pretty difficult to get right.

As an alternative you could use Trident API instead of low-level API which does provide exactly-once guarantees.

Or, as last resort, use a different system, that does provide exactly-once semantics out-of-the box.

Comment: Thanks @Matthias. Is the replay mechanism by default in Storm once you anchor the tuples? Or do you have to code it yourself by overriding the ack() and fail() methods?

Comment: If you implement your own spout, you need to implement ack() and fail(). (Storm does already provides some so-called "reliable spouts" you can just use out-of-the-box.) Of course, you also need to make sure that you spout is fault-tolerant itself, and can re-emit tuples in case fail() is called, even if the spout did fail itself in between. Furthermore, you need to assign message ID when calling emit within your spout.